# Regular expression to match word before another word or after another word

Tags: python, regex

I have a file every line of the file has the following format 
 words seprated by spaces :

word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 ...

I want to check if 2 instances of words are found on every row (the rows are scrambled on each row)

for example if i have the following rows

```
    x y z w f

    y z x f w
```

and i want to check if x and z are found on every line i apply this regex:

**x.*z|z.*x**

my question is there an optmized version for such regex ?

Comment: You just try to find your word, and if not found, usually None is returned...

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you've written works well. Here is another way of finding multiple strings on same line:

```
^.*(string1).*(string2).*$
```

Comment: This only works if `string1` and `string2` appear in that order, which is exactly the problem the OP is trying to solve.  I changed your exemplars to `string1` and `string2` to better illustrate the problem.  If that isn't what you meant, please edit the answer to make your meaning clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that , When you read your lines , split them to have a list of your word .then check with `in` operation,and use `and` to implement tow condition ,  for example :

```
>>> def finder(s):
...     l=s.split()
...     if 'x' in l and 'z' in l :
...         print 'OK'
...     else :
...         print 'Wrong'
... 

>>> s="x y p w f"
>>> finder(s)
Wrong
>>> s="x y z w f"
>>> finder(s)
OK
```

Note that you can use `in` operation at a string but as the string is concatenated maybe you have your string as a substring in another word , see the below example :

```
>>> s="this is a test " 
>>> 'est' in s
True
```